# javac complie multiple files

Tags: java, javac

I'm new to java and trying to learn the basic command line.

What is the differences between

```
javac A.java
javac B.java
javac C.java
```

and

```
javac A.java B.java C.java
```

Are there some performance issues if I use one over another?

Comment: The first alternative runs the compiler three times.  The second runs it once.  In the first case, some of the sources may be compiled more than once.

Answer (score 0):

No differences whatsoever, you can also pass directly a directory to compile all your source files (with required dependencies) like:

```
javac desiredPath/*.java
```